# What is a semantically good translation for: continue reading or read more on blog (home) pages?

Tags: translation

I am trying to build a blog home page with the usual list of article excerpts, where the excerpt contains a [read more link](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/28/designing-read-more-and-continue-reading-links/) to the complete article.

In english a *read more* link might look like:

> Continue reading “article title”

or

> read more

and similar variants.

The possible German translations (and variants):

- Weiterlesen
- Weiterlesen “article title”
- Hier weiterlesen “article title”
- Weiter geht es hier

sound weird to me, and I am German :-) .

[UPDATE]
To get an impression why I have the strange feeling with the German "solutions" just grab a screenreader and open a site like [spiegel.de](http://spiegel.de), when the text is spoken out loud, the "mehr" just doesn't feel right, in contrast the English "continue reading ..." sounds natural for me.

In a book you might find a variation of "lesen Sie weiter auf Seite xx", that does feel natural and *fits to the medium*, I try to find a natural sounding solution for a blog (digital medium) too

**Are there more and hopefully (semantically) better alternatives ?**

Comment: Weird? What's wrong with "weiterlesen"? I've seen it everywhere in WordPress blogs e.g. [DIE “WEITERLESEN”-FUNKTION](http://neontrauma.de/wordpress/die-weiterlesen-funktion.php). Sounds perfect to me and I am not German!

Comment: the strange feeling comes especially from speaking the text out loud (or take a screenreader), in english the continue reading just sounds natural and connects to the excerpt, in german "weiterlesen" does not connect (for me)

Comment: Just Weiter ([example](http://www.scilogs.de/sprachlog)) and you can also just use the headline as link.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding why "weiterlesen" is worse than "continue reading". What is so natural about the latter? For a blind person both phrases should apply equally good/bad.

Comment: for me - in german - weiterlesen sounds strange, out of context and disconnected from the preceding excerpt, it might be the same for the english version (for a native speaker), but it is not for me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Weiterlesen ...

is the best of your alternatives and is used for example in Mambo/Joomla CMS in German.

Alternatively, you can use

> Mehr ...

which is often used in German online news pages (e.g. [Spiegel Online](http://www.spiegel.de/)).

Comment: thanks for the "Mehr" variant, but as said in an above comment, my "weird" impression comes from speaking the text out loud (or use a screenreader) and the feeling that the - often used - german solution does not "connect" to the text